# How to use @Autowired in manually new instance in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, applicationcontext

As we know, `@Autowired` can be used only in instances managed by spring container, If you new an instance, and `@Autowired` member in it will not effect.

But I think In some situation, new an instance can't be avoid.

Such as a RunnableTask. which contains the DAOService, which managed by spring.  Because the task is manually new. So I can't use the DAOService in the ThreadTask.

So I want to know how to get the ApplicationContext in **Spring Boot**, and so I can get the bean by `context.getBean()`.

I knew in main() I can Autowired the ApplicationContext. But I can't pass the context as a parameter everywhere!

I want to get the ApplicationContext anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the ApplicationContext anywhere.

That's an anti-pattern. Try to avoid it.

Why can't you inject your `DAOService` into the thing that creates the `RunnableTask`?

Comment: Because the RunnableTask is created by myself, not managed by Spring. So `@Autowired` can't be autowired. @Dave

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to autowire it if you create it yourself, just inject stuff into the constructor (or a setter).

Comment: Thank for your answer, It's very useful to me. But there is still a little question, I asked in CodeReview SE. Could you please have a look at it? Thank you.[Bean Management in Spring Boot](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68139/patterns-about-bean-management-in-spring-boot)  @Dave

Answer (score 5):

How about using a factory object managed by spring?

```
class TheBeanYouWant {
    private Integer beanSupposeToAutowired;

    public TheBeanYouWant(Integer bean) {
        this.beanSupposeToAutowired = bean;
    }
}

@Component
class TheBeanFactory {
     @Autowired
     private Integer beanAutowired;

     public TheBeanYouWant  newBean() {
           return new TheBeanYouWant(beanAutowired);
     }
}
```

Comment: And I see you have more nice content - you probably want to be a bit more careful when writing more questions --- on the other hand, welcome to "upvote privilege" ;-)